# DCOM problems building a VB6 app in CruiseControl.net

Tags: iis, vb6, continuous-integration, cruisecontrol.net, dcom

I can successfully build a VB6 application that relies upon several DCOM settings on the build machine, no problem.

However. The second time I try to run the same build process, it fails, as DCOM and/or IIS have locks on the output files that I'm trynig to rebuild.

Currently, if I log onto the build machine and reset iis (using iisreset or otherwise), this releases the locks on those output files, allowing the build to complete successfully.

Obviously, I don't want to have to log onto the build machine and certainly don't want to have to keep resetting IIS - is there another way around this?

Thanks.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I've found a solution - not pretty, but it's one way around it.

Basically, prior to the build, I am calling out to a small application to kill any running processes that are going to be built during the build.  Once they're killed, the component is no longer running in memory and no longer holding a lock to the files.

As I say, there's probably a cleaner way of doing this and I will keep looking, but for now, this should suffice.